# 'Import getting started project' has encountered the problem, org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.ResolverConfiguration.setActiveProfiles(java.lang.String)'

Tags: eclipse

can anyone please help, I changed my Eclipse ide to the latest one which is 2023-06 and suddenly I am getting issues during the creation of the 'spring starter project' issue as an attached screenshot.

I uninstalled old Eclipse which has been running till now.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYQ5X.png)
I tried,

deleted .m2 and .p2 folder

uninstall maven and again install from 'eclipse market place '
uninstall old eclipse

I change  windows ->prefrences->General->NetworkConnection->change to Manual

I aspect that created the Boot project, which runs the ' maven as update ' project. should run smoothly

Comment: The latest has been 2023-0**9** for a few weeks now. This kind of error usually indicates a version mismatch.